# Track only one state React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The issue I've encountered is an infinite loop.

I have this state:

```
this.state = {
  apiData: [],
  pageNum: 1,
  isLoadingList: 0,
  search: "",
  layout: "list"
}
```

I have a function that fetch data from an API:

```
fetchApi(){
  fetch("www.api.com", ...)
}
```

And once the data fetched, it saves everything in apiData (this.state.apiData)

The thing I'm trying to do is to call that function, "fetchApi()", when "this.state.search" changes. If I do that using Lifecycle's components like componentDidUpdate(), ... it will create an infinite loop as apiData is a state too (the changes made to this.state.apiData will trigger Lifecycle's components related to states again, and again, and ...).

So I would like to track **ONLY** this.state.search and when it changes it calls the function "fetchApi()" that change this.state.apiData value.

I might trying to do something that is wrong and shouldn't be done like that, so any ideas to do the same thing but in a different way are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you're not using the *setState()* method and try to update the state directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate)

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.state.search !== nextState.state.search;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I already tried that before and didn't work and I did it again with other changes to my code and now it works as I wanted :)

Answer (score 3):

`shouldComponentUpdate` is meant to be used like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  const currentState = this.state
  return currentState.search.id !== nextState.search.id
}
```

When you update state of a component, it will trigger these methods in this order:

- shouldComponentUpdate
- componentWillUpdate
- render
- componentDidUpdate

`shouldComponentUpdate` is called just **after** the state change (with `setState`), and should return a boolean, React will not call the next methods if `false` is returned.

You should *NEVER* call `setState` from the `shouldComponentUpdate` method. It's here to prevent unneeded view calculation.

Your infinite loop, if you defined `shouldComponentUpdate` correctly, does not come from the StateChange hooks chain.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and for some reasons like I did didn't work... Change a bit of my code and add it again and now it works :)